# Why does my Flask app work when executing using `python app.py` but not when using `heroku local web` or `flask run`?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, flask, scikit-learn

I wrote a Flask-based web app that takes text from users and returns the probability that it is of a given classification (full script below). The app loads some of the trained models needed to make predictions before any requests are made. I am currently trying to deploy it on Heroku and experiencing some problems.

I am able to run it locally when I execute `python ml_app.py`. But when I use the Heroku CLI command `heroku local web` to try to run it locally to test before deployment, I get the following error

> AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'tokenize'

This error is associated with the loading of a text vectorizer called TFIDF found in the line

```
tfidf_model = joblib.load('models/tfidf_vectorizer_train.pkl')
```

I have imported the required function at the top of the script to ensure that this is loaded properly (`from utils import tokenize`). This works given that I can run it when I use `python ml_app.py`. But for reasons I do not know, it doesn't load when I use `heroku local web`. It also doesn't work when I use the Flask CLI command `flask run` when trying to run it locally. Any idea why?

I admit that I do not have a good understanding of what is going on under the hood here (with respect to the web dev./deployment aspect of the code) so any explanation helps.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from utils import tokenize  # custom tokenizer required for tfidf model loaded in load_tfidf_model()

app = Flask(__name__)

models_directory = 'models'


@app.before_first_request
def nbsvm_models():

    global tfidf_model
    global logistic_identity_hate_model
    global logistic_insult_model
    global logistic_obscene_model
    global logistic_severe_toxic_model
    global logistic_threat_model
    global logistic_toxic_model

    tfidf_model = joblib.load('models/tfidf_vectorizer_train.pkl')
    logistic_identity_hate_model = joblib.load('models/logistic_identity_hate.pkl')
    logistic_insult_model = joblib.load('models/logistic_insult.pkl')
    logistic_obscene_model = joblib.load('models/logistic_obscene.pkl')
    logistic_severe_toxic_model = joblib.load('models/logistic_severe_toxic.pkl')
    logistic_threat_model = joblib.load('models/logistic_threat.pkl')
    logistic_toxic_model = joblib.load('models/logistic_toxic.pkl')


@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('main.html')


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    """
        Takes the comment submitted by the user, apply TFIDF trained vectorizer to it, predict using trained models
    """

    text = request.form['text']

    comment_term_doc = tfidf_model.transform([text])

    dict_preds = {}

    dict_preds['pred_identity_hate'] = logistic_identity_hate_model.predict_proba(comment_term_doc)[:, 1][0]
    dict_preds['pred_insult'] = logistic_insult_model.predict_proba(comment_term_doc)[:, 1][0]
    dict_preds['pred_obscene'] = logistic_obscene_model.predict_proba(comment_term_doc)[:, 1][0]
    dict_preds['pred_severe_toxic'] = logistic_severe_toxic_model.predict_proba(comment_term_doc)[:, 1][0]
    dict_preds['pred_threat'] = logistic_threat_model.predict_proba(comment_term_doc)[:, 1][0]
    dict_preds['pred_toxic'] = logistic_toxic_model.predict_proba(comment_term_doc)[:, 1][0]

    for k in dict_preds:
        perc = dict_preds[k] * 100
        dict_preds[k] = "{0:.2f}%".format(perc)

    return render_template('main.html', text=text,
                           pred_identity_hate=dict_preds['pred_identity_hate'],
                           pred_insult=dict_preds['pred_insult'],
                           pred_obscene=dict_preds['pred_obscene'],
                           pred_severe_toxic=dict_preds['pred_severe_toxic'],
                           pred_threat=dict_preds['pred_threat'],
                           pred_toxic=dict_preds['pred_toxic'])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it. It was due to the way I picked the class instance stored in `tfidf_vectorizer_train.pkl`. The model was created in an ipython notebook where one of its attributes depended on a tokenizer function that I defined interactively in the notebook. I soon learned that pickling does not save the exact instance of a class, which means `tfidf_vectorizer_train.pkl` does not contain the function I defined in the notebook.

To fix this, I moved the tokenizer function to a separate utilities python file and imported the function in both the file where I trained and subsequently pickled the model *and* in the file where I unpickled it.

In code, I did

```
from utils import tokenize
...
tfidfvectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), tokenizer=tokenize,
                                      min_df=3, max_df=0.9, strip_accents='unicode',
                                      use_idf=1, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=1)

train_term_doc = tfidfvectorizer.fit_transform(train[COMMENT])

joblib.dump(tfidfvectorizer, 'models/tfidf_vectorizer_train.pkl')
...
```

in the file where I trained the model and

```
from utils import tokenize
...
@app.before_first_request
def load_models():
    # from utils import tokenize

    global tfidf_model
    tfidf_model = 
    joblib.load('{}/tfidf_vectorizer_train.pkl'.format(models_directory))
...
```

in the file containing the web app code.